# APEX call to a dedicated server

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

Can APEX call a code on a dedicated server?
Then Pass and retrieve variables?
Of course  I need to pass a password for the server,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible via WebServices (HttpRequest). Here's a simple example: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/NET-Development/How-to-call-net-web-service-from-salesforce/td-p/134795